# Would this example be O(n) or O(nlogn)?

Tags: big-o

I just need slight clarification on this aspect of big O -

If we had a method that had an O(logn) function before going into a O(n) function, would the overall big O of the method be O(N) rather than O(nlogn)? For example, sorting an array (an O(logN) function), followed by a for loop that iterates through the array.

Comment: The *big O* i guess you mean time complexity? What sorting function are you using? I don’t know of any below O(nlogn) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the method is invoked.

**See the below example:**

```
// O(n)
void iterate(int[] array) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
        // ...
    }
}

// O(n^2)
void doubleIterate(int[] array) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < array.length ; j ++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you invoke `iterate` from outside the for loops of `doubleIterate`, the complexity of the overall method is `O(n^2)`.

```
// O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2)
void doubleIterate(int[] array) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < array.length ; j ++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    iterate(array);
}
```

If you invoke `iterate` from within the first loop of `doubleIterate`, the complexity is still `O(n^2)`.

```
// O(n*(n+n)) = O(2*n^2) = O(n^2)
void doubleIterate(int[] array) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < array.length ; j ++) {
            // ...
        }
        iterate(array);
    }
}
```

If you invoke `iterate` from the inner loop of `doubleIterate`, the complexity of the overall method is `O(n^3)`.

```
// O(n^2*n) = O(n^3)
void doubleIterate(int[] array) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i ++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < array.length ; j ++) {
            // ...
            iterate(array); 
        }
    }
}
```